# How are the assumptions for the deduction of thermodynamics properties consistent with each other?

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity

I am looking at the deduction of thermodynamics properties, specific heat, entropy, enthalpy, and Gibbs free energy, in presence of a magnetic filed $\mathrm{B}$ of Superconductors, following the book ''Superconductivity'' by Charles P. Poole, Jr.

So if the pressure-volume work is ignored because it is negligible in SCs, the expression for the differential of Gibbs free energy density is: $dG = -SdT-\mathrm{M}\cdot d\mathrm{B}$. Very well. 
Then the author assumed we are under isothermal conditions, so $dT = 0$, then by integrating $dG = -\mathrm{M}\cdot d\mathrm{B}$ he got the expression for $G$.

But then when he deduced entropy, he just assumed now we are in constant magnetic field, so $dG = -SdT$. And $S = -dG/dT$. I am confused by this because I thought whenever you deduce a series of equations, they should be under the same assumption, and if now $dT$ is not zero anymore, how can I still use the expression for $G$ I got by assuming $dT = 0$??

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: If $dT = 0$ for a process that does not imply anything about $dG/dT$.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is a [function of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function), that is its value is determined purely by the state of the system and is independent of how that state is reached. So you can calculate $G$ considering a path at constant temperature from $B=0$ to $B=B_0$, but having calculated $G$ for some given field and temperature we no longer care about how we got there, so we are free to consider any path we like from here, such as for example one on which $B$ is constant but $T$ varies.